# bash autocomplete personal command : cannot autocomplete the argument after the option

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I wrote the autocomplete function for my command, but it is not autocomplete the argument after the option flag

```
function _qpdm_complete() 
{
    local cur prev options my_list
    COMPREPLY=()

    cur="${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORD[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    options="-opt" 
    my_list="quantum alpha betta omega operation"   

    if [[ ${cur} == -* || ${COMP_CWORD} -eq 1 ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${options}" ${cur}) )
        return 0
    else 
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${my_list}" -- ${cur}) )
    fi
}

complete -F _qpdm_complete qpdm
```

then in terminal

qpdm <TAB>

```
qpdm -opt
```

qpdm -opt<TAB>

```
qpdm -opt  
quantum alpha betta omega operation
```

qpdm -opt o<TAB>

expecting

```
qpdm -opt o
omega operation
```

but get

```
qpdm -opt o  
quantum alpha betta omega operation
```

What is missed in my _qpdm_complete()?

Comment: just guess, but maybe store my_list as an array, ie `my_list=( x y z )` and then use it like `COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "${my_list[@]}" -- ${cur}) )` (or possibly remove the dbl-quotes around `$my_list[@]}` . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter then I have as response the following "qpdm -opt  --"

Comment: something is not right. The `--` in you `compgen` command is preceded by the `${my_list[@]}` variable, but nothing is being displayed. My guess would be a misspelling either where your set `my_list` or in the cmd. Surround the `COMPREPLY=...` line like `set -x; COMPREPLY=( $(.... ) ); set +x` so you can see what values are being used for the variables. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I've added set -x ... set +x and that what I see "qpdm -opt + COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W "${my_list[@]}" -- ${cur}))
++ compgen -W quantum alpha betta omega operation --
+ set +x
" still cannot understand why ${cur} disappeared?

Comment: I got response from @fra-san on UNIX/LINUX the problem is typo COMP_WORD should be COMP_WORDS

Comment: Arg!!!! next time check your code at https://shellcheck.net (I missed that one!). Glad you found a solution.